# HP Elitebook 850 G3 notebook display very dark, no backlight

Tags: laptop, display, backlight, hp-elitebook

I have a problem that is similar to the one described a long time ago in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/421370/laptop-monitor-being-very-dark-no-backlight): My HP Elitebook 850 G3 suddenly (from one day to the next) doesn't seem to show anything on its display. Only a bit later I found out that it does indeed show the display contents, but that the backlight wasn't working.

Strangely enough, when pressing the `fn`-key and then simultaneously the `break`-key (which happens to be the right `shift`-key in combination with the `fn`-key, the backlight is turned on and stays on, as long as the `break`-key is being pressed (the `fn`-key can be released).

When the `break`-key is released, the backlight turns itself off. Completely.

Some more things to note:

- The longer the `break`-key is pressed, the longer it takes for the backlight to turn itself off when the `break`-key is eventually released - almost 1:1 in terms of duration.
- This is **not** Windows related, as the same behaviour is present within the BIOS setup
- Loading the factory defaults in the BIOS setup didn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

To narrow things down, I started to install the `HP Assistant` software, as my plan was to install everything it suggested to download/update. First item from the (long...) list was a BIOS update (the current version was from November 2020 if I remember correctly).

After installing the update and rebooting the system, the behaviour described in my question was gone - everything back to normal and the backlight works as expected.